# TI-NSPIRE CX/CAS - How to store sentences in a variable?

Tags: ti-nspire

In the notes section of the TI-NSPIRE, I keep trying to store sentences in the variable, but they keep being compiled as words multiplied together and the order of the words get rerranged. It seems to be based on alphabetical order of the first letter in the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strings.

```
S:=“this is a sentence”
```